# Paypal sandbox for manager account

Tags: paypal

I have a paypal manager account for https://manager.paypal.com/.

I want to test some api calls for recurring payment profiles. But I don't have sandbox for the same.

Can anyone know how to create a sandbox for this account?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you’re looking for. From what I can see here.

[Paypal Live or Test Transactions](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/specifying_test_or_live_transaction.htm)

Paypal manager has a test mode

Comment: I want to test this using API calls, not using PayPal web-site UI. So for testing I would require a sandbox account. How can I create it? Or is there any way I can set the test mode in API calls for the manager account?

Comment: As far as I can see it differs if you are using the rest api or the classic api.  if classic api you can log in at developer.paypal.com and create sandbox accounts (click the dashboard and sandbox appears down the side).  if its the rest api.  it looks like its just a different end point that you use.The following endpoints address our two environments:

Sandbox (for testing) : https://api.sandbox.paypal.com
Live (production) : https://api.paypal.com

Comment: I am using the classical API. Is manager.paypal.com is for REST api?

Comment: that link has the information regarding classic api and it says developer.paypal.com hope it helps

Comment: I already have a sandbox account but the thing is to update the billing cycle of already active recurring payment profiles (after discussion with paypal support), I've updated my business account to manager. But still it is not updating the billing cycle.

Comment: sorry I don't think I can help with that.  Good luck